# Regex to match unique substrings

Tags: regex, grep

Here's a basic regex technique that I've never managed to remember. Let's say I'm using a fairly generic regex implementation (e.g., grep or grep -E). If I were to do a list of files and match any that end in either `.sty` or `.cls`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls | grep -E "\.(sty|cls)$"
```

- `\.` matches literally a `"."` - an unescaped `.` matches any character
- `(sty|cls)` - match `"sty"` or `"cls"` - the | is an `or` and the brackets limit the expression.
- `$` forces the match to be at the end of the line

Note, you want `grep -E` or `egrep`, not `grep -e` as that's a different option for lists of patterns.

Answer (score 2):

```
egrep "\.sty$|\.cls$"
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex:
    \.(sty|cls)\z
will match any string ends with .sty or .cls
**EDIT:**
for grep \z should be replaced with $ i.e.
    \.(sty|cls)$
as [jelovirt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993/regex-to-match-unique-substrings#38995) suggested.